# How get user subscribers count Youtube API v3

Tags: php, youtube-api

For channel I send:

```
$videoInfo = $youtube->channels->listChannels('statistics,snippet',array(
    'id'=> $chanelId
));
```

But how get subscribers count for user ? e.g. for https://www.youtube.com/user/WarnerBrosPictures ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at example output of `listChannels` method:

```
{
  ...
  "statistics": {
    "viewCount": unsigned long,
    "commentCount": unsigned long,
    "subscriberCount": unsigned long,
    "hiddenSubscriberCount": boolean,
    "videoCount": unsigned long
  },
  ...
}
```

You have already your data, do `var_dump($videoInfo);` to see those details.

Comment: this method doesn't work for user, it works only for channels.

Comment: In fact, any user's feed has also channel ID. For Warner Bros channelID equals `UCjmJDM5pRKbUlVIzDYYWb6g`.

Comment: For using a channels legacy name (provided they have one), replace "id" with "forUsername".